# neo4j cartesian product performance improvement

Tags: neo4j, query-optimization, cypher, cartesian-product

I have a Graph database with over 2 million nodes. I have an application which takes a social graph and does some inference on it. As one step of the algorithm, I have to get all possible combinations of a relationship [:friends] of two connected nodes. Currently, I have a query which looks like:
    match (a)-[:friend]-(c), (b)-[:friend]-(d) where id(a)={ida} and id(b)={idb} return distinct c as first, d as second

So, I already know the nodes `a` and `b` and I want to get all the possible pairs that can be made from friends of `a` and `b`. 
This is obviously a very slow operation. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of getting the same result in neo4j. Perhaps adding indexes might help? Any ideas / clues are welcome!

**Example**
Node `a` has friends : `x`, `y`
Node `b` has friends : `g`, `h`, ``` i``
Then the result should be: ```
x`,`g
x`,`h
x`,`i
y`,`g
y`,`h
y`,`i`

Answer (score 1):

If you are not already you should use labels to speed up your query, which might look like:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:FRIEND]->(p3:Person),(p2:Person)-[:FRIEND]->(p4:Person)
WHERE ID(p1) = 6 AND ID(p2) = 7
RETURN p3 as first, p4 as second
```

Obviously that will rely on you having created your nodes with a `:Person` label.

How many friends does the average node have?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you also explain why this would help? I have no idea about the average number of friends but it varies greatly. Ranging from very few (less than 10) to hundreds or even thousands.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use two patterns but just one and the `IN` operator.

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:FRIEND]->(friend:Person) 
WHERE id(p) IN [1,2,3]
RETURN p, collect(friend) as friends
```

Then you have no cross product and you can also return the friends nicely as collection per person.